# Changing color of the titlebar, background and text of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am sending email from my iPhone application. Everything working fine, but I want to change the color of the title bar that appears from blue to black and the background color from white to black. Also, all the text to white color.

What should I do?  Anyone please help!

I used the below code:

```
- (IBAction)sendMail{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];

    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        [mailComposer setToRecipients: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myemail@gmail.com",nil]];

        [mailComposer setSubject: nil];

        [mailComposer setMessageBody: nil isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated: YES];

    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For changing the navigation bar color , Try this

```
 [[mailComposer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

I dont know about other two.

All The Best.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the style of `MFMailComposeViewController`.

---

Of course you *can* change it by tweaking the subviews of `mailComposer.view`, but I don't guarantee Apple will accept this.